# Want to extract part of a file name before 5th _?

Tags: bash

I have a file `abc_asdfjhdsf_ckd_dfksfj_c_12345678_223344.txt`. I want the output as `abc_asdfjhdsf_ckd_dfksfj_c.txt`.

Comment: Just extract—or did you want to rename it?

Answer (score 2):

### Using sed

```
$ echo abc_* | sed -E 's/(([^_]*_){5}).*/\1/; s/_$/.txt/'
abc_asdfjhdsf_ckd_dfksfj_c.txt
```

How it works:

- `s/(([^_]*_){5}).*/\1/`

  This captures the beginning of the file name, up to an including the fifth `_`, in group 1 and deletes the rest of it.

  In more detail, sed's substitute commands have the form `s/old/new/` where `old` is a regular expression.  In our case, the regex `([^_]*_){5}` matches the first five parts.  We put that regex in parens, `(([^_]*_){5})`, so that the first five parts are saved in group 1 which we can reference as `\1`.  `.*` matches everything after the first five groups.  We replace all of that with just the first five groups, `\1`.
- `s/_$/.txt/`

  This finds the last remaining `_` and replaces it with `.txt`.

### Using awk

```
$ echo abc_* | awk -F_ '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 ".txt"}' OFS=_
abc_asdfjhdsf_ckd_dfksfj_c.txt
```

This uses `_` as the input and output field separators.  Thus, it is just a matter of printing out the first five fields followed by `.txt`.

### Alternate approach: removing the last two parts

The above codes keep the first five parts and discard the rest.  In the sample in the question, there are seven parts, none which contain a period in them.  *If that is always the case*, then an alternate approach (hat tip: Costas) is to remove the last two parts:

```
$ echo abc_* | sed -E 's/(_[^_]*){2}\././'
abc_asdfjhdsf_ckd_dfksfj_c.txt
```

Comment: You can make the awk shorter, but arguably trickier, with `{NF=5;print $0".txt"}` or even `NF=5{print $0".txt"}`

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the original question you wanted to rename the file ending:

```
ls abc*
abc_asdfjhdsf_ckd_dfksfj_c_12345678_223344.csv

ls abc* | cut -d_ -f1-5 | awk '{print $1".txt";}'
abc_asdfjhdsf_ckd_dfksfj_c.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for   f in ./*_*_*_*_*_?*.txt
do    [ -e "$f" ] &&
      printf %s.txt\\n "${f%"${f#*_*_*_*_*_?}"}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for f in abc_*; do f="${f%_*}"; echo "${f%_*}.txt"; done
```

**Output:**

```
abc_asdfjhdsf_ckd_dfksfj_c.txt
```

`${f%_*}` is a parameter expansion pattern that will contain the value of variable `f` after removing everything after the last `_` (including).